# When upgrading from rails 5.1 to 5.2, how do you update your Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade my rails application from 5.1.4 to 5.2.

I've gone through the steps here:
https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/rails/upgrades/upgrade-rails-from-5-1-to-5-2.html

However, this completely skips over how to update your gemfile.

When I change

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
```

I receive the error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2.2) was resolved to 5.2.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.1.6.1, which depends on
        activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I can resolve these errors, but this seems to be an incomplete way to update.

What is the proper way to update your gemfile?

Comment: What command you're using? `bundle install` or `bundle update`?

Comment: Ruby Sass (the SASS parser written in Ruby) and sass-rails [are deprecated](https://github.com/sass/ruby-sass#ruby-sass-is-deprecated) and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019. You should use the [sassc-rails](https://github.com/sass/sassc-rails) gem instead. This uses [LibSass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) instead which also is quite a bit faster than the old ruby parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bundle update rails`

after this you can use gem "bundleup" to see what other gems you can update.